# run an exe and pass it an access file C++

Tags: mfc, exe, visual-c++-2008

I need to open an exe file (of an exisiting program) and load an access file in that launched program.
I have used ShellExecute to load the exe, but I could not load the access file.
What are the possible ways I could do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Most programs that loads files takes arguments that specifies e.g. files to load. This does not? Can you modify the other program to take the file to load as argument?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Joachim, I can't modify the other program. Is there a way just to pass the file needed to be load to the exe? The exe has file open option which loads the data file. How can I access that method within MFC?